# A new variant of Rotated array, how to get the index of the first minimum element after rotating using binary-search?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, binary-search

Suppose an array of length n sorted in ascending order is rotated between 1 and n times. For example, the array **nums** = [0,1,4,4,5,6,7] might become:

[4,5,6,7,0,1,4] if it was rotated 4 times.
[0,1,4,4,5,6,7] if it was rotated 7 times.
Notice that rotating an array [a[0], a[1], a[2], ..., a[n-1]] 1 time results in the array [a[n-1], a[0], a[1], a[2], ..., a[n-2]].

Given the sorted rotated array **nums** that may contain duplicates, return the index of first minimum element of this array after rotating(same as the times of rotating).

For example:

```
Input [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4] Output: 0  
Input [5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4] Output: 2  
Input [2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1] Output: 3  
Input [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1] Output: 5
```

Can we solve it using binary-search? In the worst case, the time complexity is O(n), however, it will be much better in general cases.

Comment: The answer is Yes. Google `minimum element in rotated sorted array` and you should see several solutions.

Comment: Actually this is a bit different from minimum element in rotated sorted array,  for the fourth example, we will get the '1' whose index is 0 with the method of minimum element in rotated sorted array, however, we want the '1' after '2'.

Answer (score 1):

Do a binary search and look at every position if the left neighbour is greater than the current position value. Then return the position index. Otherwise return 0.

In Python you can write

```
def search_recursive(array, start, end):
    if start > end:
        return 0

    mid = (start + end) // 2
    if mid > 0 and array[mid - 1] > array[mid]:
        return mid

    left = search_recursive(array, start, mid-1)
    right = search_recursive(array, mid+1, end)
    if left == 0:
        return right
    if right == 0:
        return left
    return min(left, right)

inputs = [[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], [5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]]
for input in inputs:
    print(search_recursive(input, 0, len(input)-1))
// Outputs:
// 0
// 2
// 3
// 5
```

The complexity is not good because you visit every element two times.

Another approach is use the binary search points and cut of some branches. For example in `[5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and the values `start=5, mid=1, succ_mid=2` and `end=4` you can concentrate the search to the array `[5, 6, 1]`. My implementation would look like the following:

```
def search_recursive(array, start_value, end_value, start, end):
    if start >= end:
        return 0
    
    mid = (start + end) // 2
    mid_value = array[mid]
    
    succ_mid = mid + 1
    succ_mid_value = array[succ_mid]

    if start_value > mid_value:
        return search_recursive(array, start_value, mid_value, start, mid)
    if mid_value > succ_mid_value:
        return succ_mid
    
    left = search_recursive(array, start_value, mid_value, start, mid)
    right = search_recursive(array, succ_mid_value, end_value, succ_mid, end)
    if left == 0:
        return right
    
    return min(left, right)

inputs = [[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], [5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]]
for input in inputs:
    print(search_recursive(input, input[0], input[len(input)-1], 0, len(input)-1))

// Outputs:
// 0
// 2
// 3
// 5
```

Comment: Could you offer the code? it is hard to understand.

Comment: I added the code in the answer. Please accept the answer if it helps you

Comment: Thanks, some questions. 1. Maybe we can delete the "if right == 0: return left" because the right can't be 0, the result may be still correct. 2. And for the first example, it seems that the program will run 13 recursive functions, which is 2*len(input)+1, Maybe it is not good as N if we visit the element sequentially.

Comment: I added a second approach. I think this would be a better seach strategy

Comment: This is better than previous one. Actually I also thought one solution. We can use the method in **minimum element in rotated sorted array**.  Then we process the special case like the fourth example by compare the first element and the last element. If they are equal, we visit the element from the end until find the '1' after '2'.